# CSV File size increased exponetially on every failure and subsequent sucessfull runs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

My python script dumps data into CSV after everyday processing is complete. For some reason CSV size has suddenly increased exponentially (actual size 0.5 to 1 GB). I have verified the script and no looping has been done to add the duplicate records to CSV.

However, there were memory exceptions in server side which led the script to fail while injecting records in DB. After clearing memory exceptions in server, subsequent runs were successful. But CSV size was increased exponentially.

My guess is CSV file memory was not released when script failed due to memory exceptions on server side. Post clearing memory issues in server, subsequent runs, CSV memory was allocated by taking consideration of the memory size that was held/unreleased during unsuccessful runs.

Another issue could be `read_csv` which was not encapsulated in `with` statment - which can be fixed, but I am more interested to know what lead CSV file size to go bigger(5 GB) than the usual size.

Note: the script are executed under Ubuntu OS.

Creation of CSV happens much before data insertion in DB,am wondering what caused CSV size to bigger even DB insertion fails due to memory exception.

Have even run the same script manually and extracted same number of records from DB and size of CSV was very small.

```
##Following are the code snippets... 

##Append extracted data to existing CSV.

with open(input_file,'a',encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore') as file:
    df_trans.to_csv(file,header=False,index=False)


##Read data in chunks,concatinate and create dataframe for intermidiate processing
data_in_chunks = pd.read_csv(input_file,error_bad_lines=False,iterator=True,chunksize=50000,
                                    warn_bad_lines=True,encoding='latin1')
df = pd.concat(data_in_chunks, ignore_index=True)

##Generate new CSV with updated dataframe for next day processing.
pd.DataFrame(df.to_csv(input_file,index=False,columns=(df.columns)))
```

Comment: your code should include the correct references to df and pd. Make it a working example. (End of Review).

Comment: @ZF007,above code snippets aren't usefull to nail down the cause,then i will have to think about writing minimal working code sample.Will update once i have the code,coming back to my problem,are there any situations that can led to exploding of CSV memory size?(additional details added to summary).

Comment: This phenomina am observing only during failures and susequent sucessfull runs.Perhaps DB memory exception raised due to CSV being consumed available memory in server.If so,then why sudden spike in CSV memory allocation?probably when first time DB memory exception raised(not sure why) file wasn't closed/not coupled `with` statment so allocated memory for CSV  didn't release to OS and python interpreter might have held it back.After clearing of DB memeory issues,in subsequent runs python iterpreter acquired memory for CSV creation and added to existing **held memory** thus size of CSV increased

Comment: Abbove comment is my suggestion and might be incorrect also.So,someone please suggest what went wrong.

Comment: I see, then it becomes hard to grasp. Can you check if there is an abundance of white-space trailing, tabulation or lengthy comma tails in the CSV file? What might help for others to help you is updating your question with software versions, nightly build versions, etc.. And if possible mark the scripts/code with server/client side labels and post some lines of the gibberish csv-file where it starts to deviate from any form of comma separation.

Comment: yes,i do see those symptoms in my CSV.Sure will update the details.